# ORO CRM in prod mode is trying to load the wrong URLs, but in dev mode it's all fine

Tags: php, twig, orocrm

ORO CRM has a piece of code that returns a requires.js config

```
requirejs.config.js.twig:

paths: {
    {% if app.debug %}
        'oro/routes': '{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback":    
        "fos.Router.setData"}) }}'
    {% else %}
        'oro/routes': {{ asset('js/routes.js', 
        'routing')|json_encode|raw }}
    {% endif %}
}
```

in dev mode (debug on), this gets rendered as

paths: {
   'oro/routes': 
   '\x2Fapp_dev.php\x2Fjs\x2Frouting\x3Fcallback\x3Dfos.Router.setData'
 }

... and this works. with the debug mode, however, this will rendered as:

```
paths: {
   'oro/routes': "\/js\/routes.js"
}
```

which, with require.js adding another ".js" extension, the browser then tries to retrieve

```
/js/routes.js.js
```

(why the backslashes?)

this doesn't work ... so why does this happen? is that a config problem somewhere? or am i too stupid?

regards

.rm

Comment: Well, backslashes are due to `json_encode`

Comment: @shukshin.ivan - really? but it seems someone thinks a slash "/" needs to be encoded ... which is not the case ... hmm. anyways. that wasn't really the problem. that's a weird thing i noticed on the side.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have empty value for next two parameters in `parameters.yml`:

`assets_version: null
assets_version_strategy: null`

Try to set values for them. For example:

`assets_version: a9f52621
assets_version_strategy: time_hash`

Don't forget to clean cache.

Comment: thank you. i will look into this. on a slight tangent: how do you even find this kind of issue. this seems like a really, really obscure problem.

Comment: Just remove `parameters.yml` in your application. Run `php composer.phar install`. Setup required parameters (DB connection settings for example), other parameters use by default. Then install application.
After that all works fine. `assets_version` will be updated automatically and after application installed it will be not `null`.